# eZ Publish extension doesn't override other extension template

Tags: php, ezpublish

I have a problem with eZ Publish and template overriding. I have two extensions named, i.e. **a** and **b**. Extension **b** extends and requires extension **a** (it is in the extensions.xml of extension **b**). In extension a I have a template file located at *a/design/oscar/templates/article/blocks/header.tpl and* I want to override it in extension **b**. I've copied the file to *b/design/oscar/templates/article/blocks/header.tpl* and made the proper changes. When I visit the site it still uses the 'base template' from extension **a**. Both of them are defined in DesignExtensions. What can be the source of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of extension.xml might be buggy depending on the version you are using.

What happens if you delete the template in your extension A ? Does it work as expected ? If yes then try to reorder your activated extensions in settings/override/site.ini.append.php to see if it works better than the solution based on extension.xml.

Another workaround would be to create a design named "oscar2", implement it in your extension B and set "oscar2" as the main SiteDesign while "oscar" will be an AdditionnalSiteDesign.

Comment: No, it doesn't work when template is deleted from extension A.

Comment: This sounds really strange. Have you clear your override cache after that (the template fallback system requires to rebuild the override cache unless this cache is disable)? Looks like extension B is not recognized as a design extension. You should double check settings/override/site.ini.append.php and extension/B/settings/design.ini.append.php